# How to select all/Unselect all check boxes from Listview in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listadapter

I want to select all/Unselect all check box.

here is my code.

```
private class BaseAdpterSendToServer extends BaseAdapter{

        String latti,calulationVal;
        String longi;
        String name;


        public BaseAdpterSendToServer(Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return AndroidCamera.imagelistcount;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

            viewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){
                holder  = new viewHolder();
                convertView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_send_to_server, null);

                holder.showImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);               
                holder.txtCalulation = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCalualtionVal);
                holder.txtLatti = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValLat);
                holder.txtLongi = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValLong);
                holder.txtName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValName);
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                holder =(viewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            int pos = 0;
            DBConnect d1 = new DBConnect(getApplicationContext(),"colorCode.db");

            pos = position+1;
            Cursor c = d1.selectedImageId(pos);


            String path = c.getString(1);
             calulationVal = c.getString(2);
             String s= calulationVal.toString();
             latti = c.getString(3);
             longi = c.getString(4);
             name = c.getString(5);
                d1.close();

          Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


            System.out.println("THE BITMAP ISK ----- "+b1);

            holder.showImage.setImageBitmap(b1);
            holder.txtCalulation.setText(""+s);
            holder.txtLatti.setText(""+latti);
            holder.txtLongi.setText(""+longi);
            holder.txtName.setText(""+name);

            bt_f_unsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        class viewHolder{
            TextView txtCalulation ,txtLatti, txtLongi,txtName;
            ImageView showImage;
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }
```

any help will be good for me.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

My suggestion is just make a button which will select/deselect all check boxes and onClick of button make a for loop to do that manually. I don't know the other way.

normally we make it like this,

```
for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
 RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(i); 
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.MyListViewCheckBox); 
cb.setChecked(true);
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: It will not help because the model remains the same. After user goes down the list, android will redraw it with old checkbox according to what adapter returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a button, which will go through your model (the data you have) and set false/true. Then you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell view to update the screen

Comment: It depends on where you get your data from. It should be loop through your array of data that provide data to the view. As I understand you request your data from DB everytime getView() is called. I wouldn't do that... Just save it in some array one time and get data from it. Then you make a loop through it and call notifyDataSetChanged() at the end